# Parse Push Notifications, how do I modify a variable in the current view controller when a notification is recieved?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, parse-platform

when my app receives a push notification I want to increment a variable i.e. totalMessages++. I know that :

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
 {

     [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
 }
```

is called when a push is received and the app is currently open. However this is declared in AppDelegate.m. How would I modify a variable in the currently displayed view controller i.e. FriendDisplayViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to begin by handling the notification & payload (read: userInfo) yourself, e.g.:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:superUniqueNotificationName
                                                      object:nil
                                                    userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

For the appDelegate & your viewController to use the same notificationName, you'll want to share it somewhere centrally (e.g.: AwesomeConstants.h/.m):

```
FOUNDATION_EXTERN NSString * const superUniqueNotificationName; // .h

NSString * const superUniqueNotificationName = @"superUniqueNotificationName"; // .m
```

Leaving your viewController to include something like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(receivedParseNotification:)
                                               name:superUniqueNotificationName
                                             object:nil];
}

-(void)dealloc {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
}

-(void)receivedParseNotification:(NSNotification *)parseNotification {
  NSLog(@"got %@ in FriendDisplayViewController, let's rock some variables", parseNotification);
}
```

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I ended up doing in the end. Thanks